# Avoid stepping out of block in Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Considering this code:

```
std::vector<myObject*> veryLargeArray;

for (int i = 0; i < veryLargeArray.size(); ++i)
{
  param_type* currParams = veryLargeArray[i]->GetParams<param_type>();
  currParams->phi = /* some complex formula */;
}
```

How would I step that code such that I know what answer is being stored in `phi` before another iteration of the loop starts which will effectively destroy `currParams` and with it my chances of watching its values in the debugger?

I am running into this situation all too often and my solution is to either recompile the code by putting a dummy variable just before the end of the block where I then put the break **OR** go through the array of values, which sometimes may be huge, just so that I can see what value was stored or may require extra work just to convert the stored `param_type` into the correct object. Both solutions are not ideal as the first introduces warnings (which is treated as an error, in which case I have to set per file rules) as well as recompilation of the code, both of which I would like to avoid, while the second wastes time.

Comment: ¤ Put a breakpoint on the assignment and then step over it. Or if Visual C++ supports that, but a breakpoint on the closing brace. Although I've never used that, I believe you can add a *data condition* on a breakpoint, e.g. some particular value of `i` that you're interested in -- check it out. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: No great solution that I know of.  I set a breakpoint in the machine code in such a case.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, all good solutions and you should definitely be able to use them in VS. To that I'll add that you can associate an action with a breakpoint which will write the value of `phi` to the debug output each iteration.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Putting a breakpoint on the closing brace does not work as any local variables inside the braces are destroyed and the _watch_ windows cannot display their value. I'll try the _data condition_ breakpoint and see if that helps

Comment: @Anton tracepoints - great idea.

Comment: @Anton: That is the best solution I have seen here, please type it out as an answer so that I can checkmark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a [tracepoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7.aspx) output the value of `phi` on each iteration through the loop. You should even be able to combine this with [breakpoint conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Set a break point on closing bracket.  Open breakpoints window (Ctrl+D, B) and in the list of breakpoints select your breakpoint.  Right click and select "Condition".  In the condition dialog enter "i==veryLargeArray.Size()-1".  Ok dialog and F5 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable declared outside of the loop to store your value between iterations and set a breakpoint on the closing bracket.

```
std::vector<myObject*> veryLargeArray;  

int inspector; // assuming currParams->phi is int, change type accordingly
for (int i = 0; i < veryLargeArray.size(); ++i) 
{  
    param_type* currParams = veryLargeArray[i]->GetParams<param_type>();   
    currParams->phi = /* some complex formula */; 
    inspector = currParams->phi;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but that would require a recompile, which is what I am trying to avoid and may pollute the code as well.